# How to handle page breaks for a long table for html to pdf conversion using java

Tags: java, itext, thymeleaf, html-to-pdf, flying-saucer

I have a thymeleaf template which I'm using to convert to pdf in java using flying saucer. The pdf that is getting generated has a long table and during page breaks the table is getting continued on new page but the table headers are not appearing on the new page.
If I open the html(thymeleaf with data) in browser and print it then table headers are appearing on new pages.
Below is the code which I'm using to convert to pdf.

```
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

private byte[] generatePdfFromHtml(String html) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(byteArrayOutputStream);
        return  byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Even it is working normally in browser but I still tried the below css, but it didn't work.

```
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

My requirement is, the table should get closed on page breaks and on new page the table headers should appear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CSS properties for printing, can you try using the below css:

```
 String css = "@page { size: auto; margin: 2cm; }"
        + "thead { display: table-header-group; }"
        + "tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }";
 //input document to the renderer 
 renderer.getSharedContext().setUserCSS(new StringReader(css));
```

Comment: cannot call `setUserCss()` on `getSharedContext()`. there is a method `setCss` but that takes some `StyleReference` as input

Comment: how about renderer.getSharedContext().getCss().add(css) ?

Comment: there is no add method available for getCss

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS, that will repeat the `thead` at the top of each page.

```css
table{
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```